# Replace hash sign using awk command

Tags: linux, bash, shell, awk

I have a `file.vcf` with the following lines. I wanted to use awk command to replace `#` in my file (please note single `#`).

```
##contig=<ID=23,length=155698556>
##INFO=<ID=PR,Number=0,Type=Flag,Description="Provisional reference allele, may not be based on real reference genome">
##FORMAT=<ID=GT,Number=1,Type=String,Description="Genotype">
#CHROM  POS     ID      REF     ALT
```

I tried `awk '/^#CHROM/{sub(/^#/,"")}​ 1' file.vcf` but it generates the following error below. What am I missing here?

```
awk: cmd. line:1: /^#CHROM/{sub$(/^#/,"")}​ 1
awk: cmd. line:1:              ^ syntax error
awk: cmd. line:1: /^#CHROM/{sub$(/^#/,"")}​ 1
awk: cmd. line:1:                    ^ syntax error
awk: cmd. line:1: /^#CHROM/{sub$(/^#/,"")}​ 1
awk: cmd. line:1:                        ^ invalid char '▒' in expression
```

Result I wanted:

```
    ##contig=<ID=23,length=155698556>
    ##INFO=<ID=PR,Number=0,Type=Flag,Description="Provisional reference allele, may not be based on real reference genome">
    ##FORMAT=<ID=GT,Number=1,Type=String,Description="Genotype">
    CHROM  POS     ID      REF     ALT
```

Comment: Why do you have `$` after `sub`?

Comment: Why do this with `awk`? `sed 's/^#CHROM/CHROM/' file.vcf`

Comment: Isn't the error message clear? It's telling you that the `$` is a syntax error.

Comment: Is `a` in the 2nd arg to `sub()` there to represent a null string because it's an unassigned variable? If so - don't do that, it just makes your code harder to understand for absolutely no reason. If you want a null string then write a null string, `""`.

Comment: @MAPK I see you quickly accepted the first answer you got. That will discourage others from providing answers and so it's only a smart move if you KNOW that the first answer you got it is the best possible answer. All the best,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`awk '{  $1 ~ "#CHROM" sub("#", ""); print }' file.vcf` worked for me. The syntax means if the first word on the line ($1) matches (~) the word '#CHROM', then substitute '#' with '' on that line and then print the line.

Comment: That command doesn't do what you described. It compares $1 to the concatenation of `"#CHROM"` and the 0-or-1 result of `sub("#", "")` and then discards the result of that comparison which would always be false anyway because a) you're comparing $1 against `#CHROM0` or `#CHROM1`, neither of which existed and b) you removed the `#` before the concatenation and so $1 is `CHROM`, not `#CHROM` at that point. Then it unconditionally prints the current line. It's also using dynamic regexps when regexp constants would make more sense and be more efficient.